# PHP. Find out MySQL database table which contains particular product

Tags: php, mysql

I have e-commerce type site with catalog page, product pages and cart. There are 3 types of dynamic product pages (because of differences between products) and also 3 tables in database. 
By clicking the **Add to Cart** button on catalog page or product page a user can add product into cart. I placed product id into variable. So I can write SQL query and fill product with info from database table.
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1
```

But how cat I find out what table should I use (in my example table1,table2 or table3)?

Here PHP code:

```
$i=0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){
    $i++;
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products_accessories WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $product_name = $row['prod_name'];
        $price = $row['price_USD'];
        $product_image = $row['main_photo'];
    }
    $total_price = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
    $ordered_quantity = $each_item['quantity'];
```

Comment: There are two ways: either you check all tables and find a proper one or pass table name (or other flag) to your script.

Comment: Why would you store the same information in three different tables?  Normally one would simply have a "products" table with the products in it.  And then select from that table.

Comment: Maybe you have to revise your table structure: you can add a filed `class` (or `type`, or `kind` ...) to classify different products types. If another product type is added, you will add another table? If you are starting the project now, I suggest you to revise table structure. Otherwise you have to search in all tables, or to add a ‘category’ option in your HTML search form

Comment: How are you keeping id unique across 3 tables? Do you have a lookup table with an iterator? If so, you could use that with some sort of class/type/etc flag as per fusion3k suggestion.

Comment: Ok, guys. Thanks for comments. I'll gather all info about products into 1 table and add category field to it.